# How to capitalize all but some letters in R

Tags: r, replace, uppercase, lowercase, capitalization

I have a dataframe in R with a column of strings, e.g. `v1 <- c('JaStADmmnIsynDK', 'laUksnDTusainS')`

My goal is to capitalize all letters in each string except 's', 't' and 'y'.

So the result should end up being: 'JAStADMMNIsyNDK' and 'LAUKsNDTUsAINS'.

Thus not changing any of the said letters: 's', 't' and 'y'.

As of now I do it by simply having 25x

```
levels(df$strings) <- sub('n', 'N', levels(df$strings))
```

But that seems to be overkill! How can I do this easily in R?

Comment: Of course, sorry - It's getting late.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
v2 <- gsub("[sty]", "", paste(letters, collapse="")) 
chartr(v2, toupper(v2), v1)
#[1] "JAStADMMNIsyNDK" "LAUKsNDTUsAINS"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("JaStADmmnIsynDK", "laUksnDTusainS")
```

Comment: That is brilliant - Thank you. 
I'll remember to make a line with the data example next time.

Comment: I have no idea why @Thigers unaccepted your solution and accepted mine. I was surprised to see that myself. Personally I think your solution is much better.

Comment: @RohitDas It's okay.  I guess he likes your solution better.

Comment: As a complete rookie in posting questions on StackOverflow I tried to accept both answers in my eager over actually receiving feedback. Sorry for that, and thank you both for the solutions. Cheers.

Comment: This is brilliant. We cannot do `gsub('([a-ru-xz])', toupper('\\1'), v1)` since `toupper()` will not work on the capture group '\1', only on a string literal.

Comment: @smci I would use `gsub('([a-ru-xz])', '\\U\\1'), v1, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: @Akrun ah thanks. '\U' operator. I'll post that as an alternative and acknowledge you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted by @akrun is indeed brilliant. But here is my more direct brute force approach which I finished too late.

```
s <- "JaStADmmnIsynDK"

customUpperCase <- function(s,ignore = c("s","t","y")) {
  u <- sapply(unlist(strsplit(s,split = "")),
              function(x) if(!(x %in% ignore)) toupper(x) else x )
  paste(u,collapse = "")
}

customUpperCase(s)
#[1] "JAStADMMNIsyNDK"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can directly `gsub()` an uppercase replacement on each applicable lowercase letter, using the perl '\U' operator on the '\1' capture group (which @Akrun reminded of):

```
v1 <- c("JaStADmmnIsynDK", "laUksnDTusainS")
gsub('([a-ru-xz])', '\\U\\1'), v1, perl = TRUE)
"JAStADMMNIsyNDK" "LAUKsNDTUsAINS"
```